# cron to run the command once in every week

Tags: linux, cron

Below cron does not seems to be working as scheduled. Can someone suggest if anything wrong here ?

I would need to run the cron every week Friday on 11:30 AM server time. here is what I have done.

```
30 11 * * 5 <path to script>
```

Comment: The expression is fine. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info to see some debugging info. It can be many things, just go through them.

Comment: from commmand line if the path to script is executed in virtual environment how shall he run the crontab which is in virtualenvironment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you put it, you might need to add a user.

Answer (score 0):

I not see any problem only that not put the user.

```
30 11 * * fri <user> <path-to-script-run>
```

Check that your user have permission for execute the script and restart crontab daemon.